# Odoo POS - Save Order from POS screen Without Payment

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I am working with the POS module in odoo. Is it possible to save an order on the POS screen without taking payment? In this case, the person keying the orders is not expected to take payments.
I mean, just creating new orders but through the POS screen.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can create a "special" payment method and validate for it on:

Addons > point_of_sale > static > src > js > screens.js

On:

module.PaymentScreenWidget.valid_order